# Checkpoints in Sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras, scikit-learn

Is there a way to save the current state of your experiment so that you can pick up from where you left off in Sklearn similar to checkpoints in Keras?

Answer (score 7):

I think the closest you can get is with either the `warm_start` parameter or the `partial_fit` call. They are available in some models and allow you to train a model several times without losing progress.

From sklearn docs:

> warm_start : bool, optional, default False
>
> When set to True, reuse the solution of the previous call to fit as
>   initialization, otherwise, just erase the previous solution.

and:

> partial_fit(X, y, classes=None, sample_weight=None)[source]
>
> Perform one epoch of stochastic gradient descent on given samples.
>
> Internally, this method uses max_iter = 1. Therefore, it is not guaranteed that a minimum of the cost function is reached after
>   calling it once. Matters such as objective convergence and early
>   stopping should be handled by the user.

Which one to use depends on what model you are using and when you want to make your checkpoints. But if you for example use a `RandomForestClassifier` which has `warm_start` you could do the following:

```
# set warm_start so model to avoid erasing model between fits
clf = RandomForestClassifier(warm_start=True)
number_of_checkpoints = 10

for checkpoint in range(number_of_checkpoints):

    # Load only a subset of the data and train on it
    X, y = load_data_batch(batches=number_of_checkpoints, current_batch=checkpoint)
    clf.fit(X, y)

    # Save model checkpoint for each fit
    with open('path/to/models/random_forest_ckp_{}.p'.format(checkpoint), 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(clf, f)
```